# Insert SQL Row via PHP into PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi im struggling to add a row into my table and cannot figure out why i have these errors.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in   C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null     given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null     given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null     given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 22

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 25
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO fixtures (ID,Date, Time, Home,     Away, Stadium) VALUES ('','', '', '', '', ''). 
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\insert.php on line 29
```

My table is as follows - 
ID(primary key autoinc), Date, Time, Home(varchar), Away(varchar), Stadium(varchar)

here is my database  connection

```
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "mancity", "fixtures");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security

$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['']);
$Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Date']);
$Time = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Time']);
$Home = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Home']);
$Away = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Away']);
$Stadium = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Stadium']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO fixtures (ID, Date, Time, Home, Away, Stadium) VALUES     ('$ID','$Date', '$Time', '$Home', '$Away', '$Stadium')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Fixture Added.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
</pre>
```

Here is my form

`<form action="insert.php" method="post">

    <p>
        <label for="Date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="Date" id="Date">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Time">Time:</label>
        <input type="time" name="Time" id="Time">
    </p>  
    <p>
        <label for="Home">Home Team:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Home" id="Home">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Away">Away Team:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Away" id="Away">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Stadium">Venue:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Stadium" id="Stadium">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>`

It is my understanding that the middle block of given data should accept the information from the form and then add it to the row . But as i said i get the error at the top of the post.

If i need to supply any more code i can do

Thanks

EDIT Small point i was struggling to post this in the format the site requires so if my blocks or code or some text is not neat or what have you, i apologise in advance.

Comment: `mysqli_connect($host, $usrname, $password, $database, $port, ....)`. What port (number) would "fixture" be?

Comment: The 5th parameter to `mysqli_connect()` should be the port number.  You have passed a string that I'm assuming is a table name.  You don't pass a specific table name to this function.

Comment: Do people just sit there and downvote every comment? People come here for help and to learn yet there is 2 replies that are trying to help yet a -1?

I should have a port number Volkerk?  on my other database connections it has only been the host, username, pass, dbname, table? what port would you suggest?
thanks for the replies patrick too

Comment: @GeorgeCawdron I didn't downvote, but I can understand why someone might. The error message is pretty clear what the error is, and checking the documentation for the function would show you the proper way to call the function.

Comment: @PatrickQ i wasnt suggesting it was you, but it seems that whenever i or someone i know comes here they get a tirade of abuse for asking for help or to learn

Comment: Why `$ID` is empty there. ? `$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['']);`

Comment: I had it as empty as it is an auto increment. @NanaPartykar

Do you know what port number the previous replies were mentioning?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeCawdron: What is `fixtures` in this line ? `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "mancity", "fixtures");`. ??

Comment: @NanaPartykar fixtures would be the table in my database.
To give an overview - I want to add a row of the attributes - Date Time Name1 Name2 Venue 
to my table - 'fixtures' in my database 'mancity'

but i want to be able to add that row via a form input on my webpage

Comment: Hi @GeorgeCawdron: Wait for my answer. Just 5-7 minutes. No issue brother. Everyone is learning here. Don't be disappointed.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeCawdron. Please have a look on answer. Please respond me back with issues / error you getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  <p>
      <label for="Date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" name="Date" id="Date">
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="Time">Time:</label>
      <input type="time" name="Time" id="Time">
  </p>  
  <p>
      <label for="Home">Home Team:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Home" id="Home">
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="Away">Away Team:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Away" id="Away">
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="Stadium">Venue:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Stadium" id="Stadium">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**insert.php**

I hope `mancity` is your database name.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mancity");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security

$Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Date']);
$Time = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Time']);
$Home = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Home']);
$Away = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Away']);
$Stadium = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Stadium']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures`(`Date`, `Time`, `Home`, `Away`, `Stadium`) VALUES('$Date', '$Time', '$Home', '$Away', '$Stadium')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Fixture Added.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! you are a hero! Checked my db and its in there too.

I will look over your code and see how it works. Again thank you so much!

Comment: Yes it worked (caught the return key so it posted mid reply)
Thank you again :)

Comment: "*.. you are a hero!* " Made My Day. Thank You. And Remember, *Never Be Disappointed* @GeorgeCawdron

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

after closing connection you use pre, it seems weird

> and mysqli_escape_string    use for escape special character

Comment: the </pre> is me trying to get the original post to fit the requirements of the site, thats not actually in my code but thank you for noticing and suggesting it